# Wep Api inside a Wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, iis, webapi

I have a wordpress site that runs under a specific Server. Inside that wordpress folder site i have put a folder named "API" of a web api which normally is not part of wordpress site. By hit the following url

"Domain of site/API/CheckIban?username=""&apiKey=""&Iban="" "

Returns me "Page not found". Of course i hit the url with correct parameters for username e.t.c. not just "".

I know this is very strnge thing to ask but it what it is...
Does anyone have an idea what goes wrong here or a suggestion how to be done properly in order an external folder can work under a wordpress folder and give as result an xml output ?

The web server is IIS

Comment: This might point you in the right direction. https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for your answer but i believe its more complicated that simply edit the permalink... Since its an external web app which resides at the same folder with the root of the wordpress site...

Comment: My comment was not an answer. My point is that WordPress edits the URLs of all requests coming into a site according to its permalink rules. Your API's URL gets edited with all the rest, hence your error.

Comment: If you wan to make wordpress application work well on IIS, you need to configure a rewrite rule for it so that URL can be handled in wordpres correctly. `rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">  <match url=".*" /> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />     </conditions>    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>`